# Strapi doesn't return data for default locale via REST API

Tags: internationalization, locale, strapi

I'm using the latest `Strapi` version (4.5.2) and have two locales configured:

```
https://my-api-url.com/api/i18n/locales ->
    
0   
    id          2
    name        "German (de)"
    code        "de"
    createdAt   "2022-11-23T17:15:52.629Z"
    updatedAt   "2022-11-23T19:58:50.165Z"
    isDefault   false
1   
    id          1
    name        "English (en)"
    code        "en"
    createdAt   "2022-11-22T14:31:35.679Z"
    updatedAt   "2022-11-23T19:59:05.421Z"
    isDefault   true
```

When I query my Strapi API without specifying a `locale` parameter, [it should return the content in the default language](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/i18n.html#getting-localized-entries-with-the-locale-parameter) (here, as shown above, "English"), but it doesn't:

```
https://my-api-url.com/api/mycollection ->

data    []
meta    
pagination  
page    1
pageSize    25
pageCount   0
total   0
```

Querying with `locale` set to "German", I get the expected contents:

```
https://razor-server-tim.herokuapp.com/api/themes?locale=de ->

data    
    0   
        id  2
        attributes  
            Title   "Das ist mein Titel"
            Summary "Das ist die Zusammenfassung"
            SomeOtherField "Deutsche Übersetzung"
            createdAt   "2022-11-23T19:41:11.527Z"
            updatedAt   "2022-11-23T19:41:21.162Z"
            publishedAt "2022-11-23T19:41:21.156Z"
            ImageUrl    "https://res.cloudinary.com/hnraymasy/image/upload/v1669146049/car_vxhq7h.png"
            locale  "de"
meta    
    pagination  
        page    1
        pageSize    25
        pageCount   1
        total   1
```

Querying the API with `locale=all` results in only the German translations being returned.

(From the docs: *"Use `all` as a value for the locale code, as in `http://localhost:1337/api/restaurants?locale=all`, to fetch entries for all locales that have been configured in the admin panel.)*

In the Global Settings, the i18n plugin is configured as shown:

[image: Strapi i18n Global Settings]

The collection type page shows that both locales have content available:

[image: Strapi collection type locales]

The entry itself also shows that English content is available:

[image: Strapi item with locales]

Why does the API not return my English content?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the time was late... Turns out that I mixed up the locally and remotely deployed versions and edited the unpublished draft for the English `locale`.

**(－‸ლ)**

So make sure that you actually publish the version that you're requesting via the API!

[image: Publish, save, draft version]